# IBM Worklight 6.1 support to iOS 9

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have an App built with worklight 6.1 ,to support iOS9,as per my understanding we need to first build an IPA using BuildEnvoy, targeting to iOS v9 and secondly  most important we need to know whether or worklight 6.1 will support to iOS 9 SDK or not..
as per the information I have, BuildEnvoy is going to support iOS beta version in few days.. 
did any one have any information  worklight 6.1 will support to iOS9?,
Do they are going to provide any fix pack to worklight 6.1 or how it will be...

Any thoughts or comments will  really helpful to me to start  testing in iOS 9 beta version

Answer (score 0):

In the near-future (September) there will be iFixes available for providing required iOS 9 fixes and instructions, from Worklight 6.0 to MobileFirst Platform 7.1

In the meanwhile you can start by reading the following blog posts:

- [ATS and Bitcode in iOS 9](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/24/ats-and-bitcode-in-ios9/)
- [MobileFirst Platform support for iOS 9 (betas 1-5), status report](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/17/mobilefirst-platform-support-for-ios-9/)

Comment: or anyone have any idea whether or not the worklight/mobilefirst  iFIX is available for 6.1,if yes can let me know the process to apply or any link will really helpful,if no when it will be available .

Comment: IFixes have been released for all releases of worklight and are available in IBM Fix Central